# FXML getLocation() returns null even though I think I am setting it correctly

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

When I try to link my FXML sheet to my main class, I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2463)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2439)
        at com.nandha.client.start(client.java:28)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        ... 1 more
```

Here is my start method

```
        stage.setTitle("Client");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Main.fxml"));
        System.out.println(loader.getLocation()); //Prints Null
        VBox box1 = loader.<VBox>load(); //Code Breaks Here

        Scene scene = new Scene(box1, 300, 150);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

And here is my FXML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<VBox fx:controller="com.nandha.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
        <Text fx:id="status" text="Not Connected"/>
        <Button  fx:id="connect" text="Connect" onAction="#connectToServer"/>
        <Button fx:id="buttonNew" text = "Add New Patient" onAction="#openCreateNewPage"/>
        <Button fx:id="buttonUpdate" text="Existing Patient"/>
</VBox>
```

The FXML file, main class and the corresponding class are all in the same folder and package, src/com/nandha/. I have tried with and without the slash in front of main, and adding the package name.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: For some reason, the location started working when I removed fx:controller="com.nandha.Controller" from the xml file, can someone help as to why this is causing a problem?

Comment: Did you ensure that the fxml file is still in the same package as the `.class` files, after building?

Comment: Thank you for the help, but unfortunately no. Is there a possibility something other than the file path is causing the problem because the set location method was working fine until I made a couple of changes to the Controller and XML files

Comment: I played around a little bit more, and found that the controller specifier in the FXML file is causing the problem, I have edited the post accordingly.